# Initializing Class with constructor with an iList<T>?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

first question on S.O, and all around newbie at the moment.

I'm trying to create a Json file from an object right now for a game. This is the main object I want to write to a file: 
(classes "block", and "items" are the iLists, as you can probably tell)

```
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string map { get; set; }
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string champion { get; set; }
    public int sortrank { get; set; }
    public bool isGlobalForChampions { get; set; }
    public bool isGlobalForMaps { get; set; }
    public bool priority { get; set; }
    public IList<Block> blocks { get; set; }
    public IList<object> associatedChampions { get; set; }
    public IList<object> associatedMaps { get; set; }

    public ItemSet(string _title, string _type, string _map, string _mode, string _champion, int _sortrank, bool _isGlobalForChampions, bool _isGlobalForMaps, bool _priority, IList<Block> _blocks, IList<object> _associatedChampions, IList<object> _associatedMaps)
    {
        title = _title;
        type = _type;
        map = _map;
        mode = _mode;
        champion = _champion;
        sortrank = _sortrank;
        isGlobalForChampions = _isGlobalForChampions;
        isGlobalForMaps = _isGlobalForMaps;
        priority = _priority;
        blocks = _blocks;
        associatedChampions = _associatedChampions;
        associatedMaps = _associatedMaps;
    }

public class Block
{
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

But I get a distinct feeling I'm going about this in all the wrong ways. I actually used a Json to C# generator to discover (after many failed manual attempts) to give me an idea of the kinda variables I might need to consider using. But I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax for initializing an iList<> with a constructor, and no amount of bad googling is bringing me closer to that answer.

Current intialization: (missing the last 3 arguments, obviously)

```
ItemSet itemSetTest = new ItemSet("TEST_ITEM_SET", "custom", "any", "", "Kalista", 0, false, true, false, );
```

If I haven't provided enough/the right info please don't hesitate to be blunt!

Side things:
I presume I will be adding to the lists as I would with any other array?
Is this a totally terrible way of doing this?

Comment: `IList<T>` is the interface, use `List<T>` such as `IList<T> blocks = new List<Block>()`

Comment: See [Object and Collection Initializers in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

remove the constructor you have, you don't need it.

```
itemSet = new ItemSet {
  title="...",
  ...,
  blocks=new List<Blocks>() { 
    new Block {
      type="...", 
      items=new List<Item>() {
        new Item { count=..., id=...},
        new Item { count=..., id=...}
      }
    },
    new Block {
      type="...", 
      items=new List<Item>() {
        new Item { count=..., id=...},
        new Item { count=..., id=...}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought a constructor is to keep the initialisation on a single line, I like how neat it is. And thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

That's the way to go -

```
new List<Item> () {
          new Item(),
          new Item(),
          new Item(),
          new Item()
    };
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to instantiate your class; you will need to pass through new List items to your constructor. For example:

```
//add items to these lists and change names if needs be.
var blocks = new List<Block>();
var champs = new List<Object>();
var maps = new List<Object>();

var itemSetTest = new ItemSet("TEST_ITEM_SET", "custom", "any", "", "Kalista", 0, false, true, false, blocks, champs, maps);
```

Essentially a List implements IList. IList is an interface and as such cannot be instantiated. But because List implements IList, you can pass a List across to your constructor and it will accept it.

I hope that answers your question.

I also want to mention that your constructor is incredibly large (Oh matron). You might want to think about creating a few more classes and combining these properties. You may also consider having default values for some of these properties; for instance if string champion is usually "bob" you could set that as a default and only pass the champion string in to the constructor when the name is different.

I'm also assuming that your ItemSet class (maybe think of a more meaningful name)  is in fact a class and you just having copied some of the wrapping code block?

---

## Update 1

> When you say to combine the properties, do you mean to use
>   inheritance?

Not quite, but maybe I didn't word it properly. I mean grouping related properties in to their own classes. Lets take a simple example or a Person class:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string TwitterUrl { get; set; }
        public string FacebookUrl { get; set; }
        public string GooglePlusUrl { get; set; }

        public Person(string name, string postcode, string town, string country, string twitterurl, string facebookurl, string googleplusurl)
        {
            Name = name;
            Postcode = postcode;
            Town = town;
            Country = country;
            TwitterUrl = twitterurl;
            FacebookUrl = facebookurl;
            GooglePlusUrl = googleplusurl;
        }
    }
```

Creating an instance of type Person is going to be a bit tedious, hard to read and hard to maintain:

```
var person = new Person("Some name", "some postcode", "some town", "some country", "some twitter url", "some fb url", "some g+ url");
```

Lets simplify it by grouping relevant properties in to their own classes:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public SocialMedia SocialMedia { get; set; }

        public Person(string name, Address address, SocialMedia socialmedia)
        {
            Name = name;
            Address = address;
            SocialMedia = socialmedia;
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class SocialMedia
    {
        public string TwitterUrl { get; set; }
        public string FacebookUrl { get; set; }
        public string GooglePlusUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Now our Person only has properties and you can instantly see what is going on. We've decreased the size of the constructor to a more manageable state:

```
var address = new Address() { ... };
var socialmedia = new SocialMedia() { ... };
var person = new Person("Some name", address, socialmedia);
```

For me, that's more readable. Your Address & SocialMedia models can be reused elsewhere in the app too.

> I have been trying to figure how to serialize multiple objects
>   (json.net) to the same file without any luck for about a week, and had
>   decided to just try to keep everything in single class.

json.net by Newtonsoft (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)? If not, then I recommend you use this library as it has become standard.

To Serialize our declared `person` you will need to use the following method provided by json.net:

```
//...
var person = new Person("Some name", address, socialmedia);
string personJsonified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

This will generate a json string of our person.

However, you want multiple objects. If you want multiple Person objects you could create a list and serialize that:

```
    var person1 = new Person("Jim", address, socialmedia);
    var person2 = new Person("Bob", address, socialmedia);
    var people = new List<Person> { person1, person2 };

    string peopleJsonified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people);
```

If you want multiple types to be returned in the json string, such as Person and Car (a fictional class we've created), you would need to wrap these up in some other class:

```
            var myPerson = new Person("Jim", address, socialmedia);
            var myCar = new Car();
            var randomObjects = new SomeRandomObjects{ Person = myPerson, Car = myCar };

            string randomObjectsJsonified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(randomObjects);
```

Hopefully you'll get you will be able to get your json file generated from this.

> Also got any naming convention tips?

As for naming conventions and guidline, check out [MSDN Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: When you say to combine the properties, do you mean to use inheritance?

I have been trying to figure how to serialize multiple objects (json.net) to the same file without any luck for about a week, and had decided to just try to keep everything in single class. After thinking about proper question asking etiquette, I realise I have let another problem cause an abstracted question to a degree, and for that I apologise.

Also got any naming convention tips?

Comment: To be honest, I have included more properties in this class than I originally intended, and in-fact many will not be used very often, if at all. So after I solve my problem I'll be removing some, and hopefully learning how to serialize more than one object into a single file.

Comment: @ConorMacF I've updated the answer with answers to your question in the comments. Hope it helps a bit. I would concentrate on getting it working first, then come back to it and refactor. It seems like you have most of the code set up already anyway, so you're almost there.